# Blender 2.8 How to inset faces and bevel into an oval

Tags: bevel

I'm looking to recreate the effect seen in the video linked. I've linked it at the start of the part and it runs for about 40 seconds. I'm trying to recreate the rounded inset faces. I can get the faces to inset just fine, but then they do a lot of things in rapid succession and I'm getting lost. Pretty new to blender so if you can be detailed that would be very much appreciated. [Imperial Shuttle in Blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myERqlkVwBU&t=38m55s)

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Just slow the video to 0.25 speed and it's all pretty clear. Steps after the insetting: 1. Invert selection (*Ctrl+I*), 2. Delete selected faces (*Delete >Faces*), 3. Bevel vertices (check *only vertices*), 4. Add a solidify modifier. Also don't forget, that in [38.58] they duplicated and separated the selection into a new object.

Comment: @JachymMichal you should put that as an answer

Comment: @JachymMichal So what you said makes a lot of sense. The bit I missed was definitely duplicating the selection. That part I didn't catch. One other thing that has me confused, my vertex bevel is looking very different than the one in the video. Where as his constrains to the corners and rounds the rectangle, mine seems to make an oval. Here is a screen recording. Any tips here? Thanks again for the welcome and help! Very appreciated.
https://youtu.be/jPOISYcntNY

Comment: Hello :). You need to apply your object scale. Go to *Object > Apply > Scale*, and all your transforms will work correctly.

Comment: You are my hero. :D If you want to respond with that last as an answer I'll mark that as the answer and everything! Now I'm going to have to go look up what the apply scale does and everything so I understand what just happened. Thank you thank you thank you!